# The FileLauncher doen't work as the docs show

Tags: uwp

The sample code should show the pick to select the target app to launch file.

Docs from : https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-the-default-app-for-a-file

```
        var file = await MyLibrary.UWP.StorageItemPicker.OpenSingleFileAsync(".mp3");
        if (file != null)
        {
            // Set the option to show the picker
            var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();

            options.DisplayApplicationPicker = true;
            //options.LimitPickerToCurrentAppAndAppUriHandlers = true;

            // Launch the retrieved file
            bool success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file, options);
            if (success)
            {
                // File launched
            }
            else
            {
                // File launch failed
            }
        }
```

but the code in my app can 't work, it doesn't show she selector ui,and the file won't launch.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Could you please provide more information to help us further check the problem for you?1. `MyLibrary.UWP.StorageItemPicker.OpenSingleFileAsync` What does this function implement? 2. Is your project a UWP project? If it is a UWP project, could you try to use [UWP PickSingleFileAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-using-file-and-folder-pickers#pick-a-single-file-complete-code-listing) 3.`The code in my app can 't work` Which specific line of code does not work, is there any error code or return value?